# How is the length of the six measured instantly?

Tags: cricket, technology

How is the length of the six measured instantly in cricket? What technology do they use?

Answer (score 3):

Radar gun is used to calculate the bowling speed in cricket.A simple example showing the use on **http://www.bigbro.in/blog/how-is-the-bowling-speed-and-lengthdistance-of-the-sixes-hit-in-cricket-measured/**

How it works?

Radar gun is the current or present technology to calculate the speed of bowl. Radar gun has both radio transmitter and the receiver. This device works on the principle of "Doppler effect." It sends the radio waves to the receiver. They emit a radio signal in a narrow beam and receive the same signal after it bounces from the target particle.

Another method,

Hawk eye method
It uses six specially placed cameras around the ground to track the path of the ball, from when it was released from the bowler's hand right up until when it's dead. with the combined effect of these six camera's a 3-D image is formed and is used to measure the speed of the ball bowled.

This same technology is used to calculate the distance of the six hit by the batsman.

Comment: link not working

Comment: link to the article is dead.

Answer (score -6):

First they calculate the **speed of the ball** after hitting the bat taking distance as **22 yards** (changing it into meters) and then **record the time till the ball crossed the pitch by d=s/t** then they record the **time till the ball has stopped outside** the playing area then again they calculate the distance by *d=s/t* . this is how it is calculated

(all calculations are based on the assumptions that speed of the ball remains the same )

Comment: Any *official* reference?

Answer (score -7):

Actually its a good question.I just find these answer with these [reference](https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120525032513AAzcZHg).

I can present `two` different ways.

- Based on the angle of hitting.

  using range of a projectile formula.

  > R=v² Sin (2Θ)/g
  >
  > ```
  > Where : v= velocity at time of hitting… 
  >
  > g= 9.8 m/s^2 
  >
  > Θ= Angle at which ball is hit.
  > ```

  [Ideal_projectile_motion_for_different_angles](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/61/Ideal_projectile_motion_for_different_angles.svg)
- Using initial velocity & acceleration of the ball

  > S = ut + 0.5at²
  >
  > ```
  > t = the time the ball stays in the air 
  > u = initial velocity at which the ball left the bat (calculated like bowling speed) 
  > a = 9.8 m/s^2 
  > s= distance travelled by the ball
  > ```

  ```
    It's broadcaster choice to use different scientific approaches to find the distance travelled by the ball.
  ```

Comment: -1: Yahoo answers is not a reliable source, and although the equations given could be used, (preferably in a cricket ground with no air resistance), I doubt that they are.

Comment: Welcome to Sports.SE, Summarize the answer in your own words. Though this post is all about technology, you can provide your own words about what you had understand/know about that, since we [discourage](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/a/193/753) plagiarism here in Sports.SE.